# Determine Shop To Which Fulfilled Order From Webhook Belongs

Tags: shopify

I have a Shopify app that creates a webhook for orders/fulfilled when a shop signs up, I also save some details about the shop as well as it's products.

When Shopify sends me fulfilled orders via the webhook, i want to associate this order with the appropriate shop to which it belongs.

I have looked in the data sent, but there's no shop name or shop url.

Is there a way for me to determine which shop the orders belong to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have setup a Webhook then you know two things for sure.

1. The domain of the shop calling you is in the header
2. There is authentication information in the header you have to use

If you are not authenticating your webhook you're doing it wrong. So the short answer to determining which shop is calling you is to look inside the header for the domain.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into the header and found the shops url.
But I don't really know how to authenticate, how would i go about it?
Thanks again.

Comment: @DavidLazar s answer is great. The header 'HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_DOMAIN' contains the shop name. The header 'HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_TOPIC' contains the topic, e.g. 'orders/create'.

I have no idea why none of this is in the Shopify docs.